# Print blank space in bash script

Tags: bash, printf

Why such script:

```
x=xxx
y=yyy
printf -v var "%s %s" "$x" "$y"
printf $var
```

prints only:
`xxx`

While I expected:
`xxx yyy`

How to force `printf` not ignore symbols after blank space?

Comment: `printf "$var"`

Comment: `printf "$var"` only works if there is no `%s` or similar in the string.  Better use `printf "%s\n" "$var"` or plain old simple `echo "$var"`.

Comment: Or just: `printf '%s' "${x} ${y}"`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
#!/bin/bash
x=xxx
y=yyy
var=`printf "%s %s" $x $y`
echo $var
```

?